# PhpStorm phpUnit autocomplete broken because of setUp method

Tags: php, unit-testing, autocomplete, phpunit, phpstorm

Make PhpStorm autocomplete fields defined in phpUnit's setUp method.

If I define a mock in setUp method:

```
public function setUp()
{
    $this->testRepo = $this->getMockBuilder(TestRepository::class)
        ->disableOriginalConstructor()
        ->getMock();
}
```

When I want to use this mock in other methods:

```
public function testExample()
{
    $this->testRepo->.... at this point phpStorm does not show autocomplete        options
}
```

I understand that phpStorm doesn't know that setUp method is run before each other test method but maybe there's a way to fix this behavior.

I also don't want to add phpDoc to each property defined. I find this pretty robust and ugly:

```
/**
 * @var PHPUnit_Framework_MockObject_MockObject
 */
protected $testRepo;
```

PS: Stackoverflow editor is s**t

Answer (score 2):

Change the PHPDoc annotation as follow:

```
/**
 * @var \PHPUnit_Framework_MockObject_MockObject|TestRepository
 */
protected $testRepo;
```

hope this help

Comment: This is not what i want to accomplish. I don't want to add to each mock phpDoc block. 
I don't care about the TestRepository class autocomplete. I want autocomplete for PHPUnit_Framework_MockObject_MockObject class.

Comment: Add a `\ ` before `PHPUnit_Framework_MockObject_MockObject`

Comment: "I don't want to add to each mock phpDoc block" - tough break, because there's no other way for phpstorm to reliably resolve the field type. Docblocks became a de facto standard and I'd recommend to start using them for all your fields. You can go to Settings -> Editor -> General -> Code Folding and collapse them by default if you don't want them to take space.

Comment: I am using phpDoc blocks for every method and property i define. The reason I don't want to use them in this case is because almost all the test class properties (except the class i am testing) will be php unit mocks, instance of PHPUnit_Framework_MockObject_MockObject. So, they will have the same phpDoc block: /** @var PHPUnit_Framework_MockObject_MockObject */